# Real factors of the polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem, it would help me.

The task is:

Find the real factors of the polynomial:

a)$P(x)=x^{4}+1$

b)$P(x)=x^{2n}+1,n\in N$

I don't know where to start with this task.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

For part (b), if $x\gt0$ or $n$ is even,
$$
P(x) = x^{2n} + 1 = x^{2n} + 2x^n + 1 - 2x^n = (x^n + 1)^2 - 2x^n = (x^n-\sqrt{2x^{n}} + 1)(x^n+\sqrt{2x^{n}} + 1)
$$
For (a), put $n=2$

Answer (score 1):

a)

$\begin{align}x^4+1&=(x^4+2x^2+1)-2x^2\\&=(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt{2}x)^2\\&=(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)\end{align}$

b)

For $n$ is even:

$\begin{align}x^{2n}+1&=(x^{2n}+2x^n+1)-2x^n\\&=(x^n+1)^2-(\sqrt{2}x^\frac{n}2)^2\\&=(x^n+\sqrt{2}x^\frac{n}2+1)(x^2-\sqrt2x^\frac{n}2+1)\end{align}$

For $n$ is odd:

$\begin{align}x^{2n}+1&=(x^2)^n+1\\&=(x^2+1)(x^{2(n-1)}-x^{2(n-2)}+\cdots+(-1)^{(n-k)}x^{2(n-k)}+\cdots-x^2+1)\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Split the polynomial $x^4+1$ into linear factors in $\mathbf C$ first. Its  roots are the fourth roots of $-1$. As it is a polynomial with real coefficients, its roots are pairwise conjugate, and in the final step, you only have to group conjugate linear factors to obtain irreducible quadratic factors with real coefficients.

Same method for $x^{2n}+1$. To  determine the $2n$-th roots of $-1$, use the exponential form of complex numbers:

$-1=\mathrm e^{i\pi}$, therefore a $2n$-th root $z$ will have modulus $1$ and we write it as $z=\mathrm e^{i\theta}$, so we have to solve
$$z^{2n}=\mathrm e^{2in\theta}=\mathrm e^{i\pi}\iff2n\theta\equiv \pi\pmod{2\pi}\iff \theta\equiv\frac{\pi}{2n}\pmod{\frac\pi n}.$$
Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

As $x^4+1>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, it is clear that $X^4+1$ has no real roots.

So if it factorises it will factorise as $X^4+1=(X^2+aX+b)(X^2+pX+q)$.

Equating coefficients of $X^3$ gives $p=-a$; then equating coefficients of $X$ gives $b=q$, so that $X^4+1=(X^2+aX+b)(X^2-aX+b)$.

Hence $b=\pm 1$ and $2b=a^2$. Hence $b=1$ and $a=\sqrt{2}$.

This agrees with @Student1058's slick solution, but I offer you this anyway as it requires no thought whatsoever.